# Google Maps API v3: lock area from dragging

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, drag

I'm looking for a way to border the area (in my case: The Netherlands) in the Google Maps API v3 and stop the user from dragging the map outside of the border. The option I think I need is drag(+)(end,ging etc.) described at the following link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference . Found alot of examples already but they don't seem to fit in my code. Here is the javascript part of the API:

```
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {

zoom: 1,                                                //zoomValue                                                 
minZoom: 7,                                             //minimumValue zoom    
center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.088282, 5.477124),    //position center map (geoLocation)
mapTypeControl: true,                                   //mapType (cart/satelite)
mapTypeControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
},
panControl: false,                                      //panControl (moveLeft/moveUp/moveRight/moveDown)
panControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
},
zoomControl: true,                                      //zoomControl (zoomIn/zoomOut)
zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
},
scaleControl: true,                                     //scaleControl
streetViewControl: true,
streetViewControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    }
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                            mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Did you find the way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

you just need to add

```
draggable: false
```

in the options list

Comment: Hmm maybe I wasn't clear enough. Then I can't drag inside that area, thats what I meant. Only if I try to get out of the borders it should stop dragging. Thanks anyway